# Did a Hungarian bus driver scare his passengers with these pranks?

Tags: humor

[9Gag](http://9gag.com/gag/anYVZmL?ref=fsidebar) has a post telling the story of a Hungarian bus driver who trolled his passengers. Some comments on 9gag and other places on the internet claim that the story is true, but they are not sourced at all. Did what is described really happened?

[The story in "Rage Comics" format](http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/anYVZmL_700b_v1.jpg)

The text of the image is:

> Let me tell you the story of a hungarian bus driver who knew the art of trolling.
>
> Dressed as a blind man, he approached his bus, got on while tripping on the steps a little, started the engine, then drove off while the passengers were screaming for mercy.
>
> The company had no sense of humor, so he got a warning.
>
> The next time, he sat at the back pf the bus with the rest of the passengers. When the bus should've left 15 minutes ago and the passengers got impatient, he got up and yelled: "If the driver won't do his job, I am gonna drive this shit!" and started for the driver's cabin. The bus was empty in 5 seconds.
>
> The company said no more jokes while on duty.
>
> His last gag was while driving the bus down the hill. Before starting his route, he had sneaked up a spare wheel, and as the bus was going downhill he threw it out from his cabin yelling "OMG OMG THE WHEEL BROKE OFF, THE MOTHERFACKING WHEEL JUST BROKE OUT OF ITS PLACE!". No need to say the passengers freaked out and started screaming for their lives.
>
> The company was so mad at him, he was fired immediately.

Comment: I suggest only including the text of the story and not the images. It would be an easier to read, more focused question.

Comment: @Articuno, done

Comment: There was a case of a bus driver in Hungary [fired in 2012](http://hvg.hu/itthon/20120621_bkv_kirugas) (note: link is in Hungarian) for inappropriate behaviour.  From what I can tell, his crimes included announcing bus stations in a funny matter, and painting the bus service in a negative light in a TV interview.  From the article, this seems to have been public knowledge (little introduction is made), and the news source (HVG) is a relatively highly regarded magazine (normally dealing with economics issues).

Comment: ... I did not see anything related to throwing wheels out of a moving vehicle, and neither of the first two claims are explicitly backed up (although they seem to be more within character).  Perhaps someone else can follow up.